# When did javascript add "touch" events

Tags: javascript, touch

I would be interested to know a little about the history of the process of implementing touch events into the javascript language, such as when, but, better yet, the process by which the javascript developers decided on the rules for the touch api (is it an api?).

Also, do all touch devices adhere to a standard set of rules ... they would have to, right? otherwise how could javascript's touch api be cross-device dependable.

**EDIT:** wouldn't implementing a touch api into javascript constitute a new version of javascript?

Answer (score 2):

> wouldn't implementing a touch api into javascript constitute a new version of javascript?

Its important to recognize that the word Javascript can refer to many different things.  There's the official ECMAScript spec, and then there are various implementations by different browsers and server-side environments.  These implementations all implement different parts of the ECMAScript spec.  Generally they each include some subset of the spec, along with some proprietary features as well. There were implementations of touch APIs (going back to safari on the original iPhone at least) well before it was part of the official spec.

Comment: +1 "javascript" and "JavaScript" have become generic terms for ECMAScript, but should probably be restricted to ECMAScript in a browser or at least host environment involving a document. Strictly, JavaScript™ is Mozilla's (formerly Netscape's) implementation of ECMAScript.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the spec that defines these events http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/, where it says:

> Implementations that use ECMAScript to implement the APIs defined in
>   this specification must implement them in a manner consistent with the
>   ECMAScript Bindings defined in the Web IDL specification [WEBIDL] as
>   this specification uses that specification and terminology.

JavaScript is ECMAScript, or if you will, the ECMAScript implementation from Mozilla.